# Obtain OAuth Credentials for my own GMail account

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I was using the older JavaMail API to send email from my Android app using password based authentication. The thing is that I am using my *own* GMail account for sending email (thus storing email/password in code - I know that is not a good idea)

`new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass)`

I have now upgraded to the newer version of JavaMail and I want to use OAuth2

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
```

How do I generate OAuth credentials for my own GMail account and use them to send email?

---

EDIT:

This is what I tried so far:

1. Created a project on [Google Console](http://console.developers.google.com). From the Credentials screen, create OAuth Client ID - choose "Other". This gives me Client ID and Client Secret
2. Using [oauth2.py](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough), used the Client ID and Client Secret to generate an Access Token and a Refresh Token (In the production app, I intend to hard code all 4: client id, secret, access, refresh token and continue using them "forever" for generating new access tokens)
3. Tested that SMTP Authentication works using oauth2.py
4. Modified my Java code for sending the mail as follows:

   ```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.debug", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 587);
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

   Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
   SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null);
   transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", _user, _accessToken);
   transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
   ```

And now I am getting:
`java.net.UnknownHostException: mail.google.com Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com`

I am having trouble finding how to set the Access Token on the request. Instead of

`transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", _user, _accessToken);`

I have also tried

```
String auth = new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", _user, _accessToken).getBytes()));
transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + auth, 235);
```

But same error.

Comment: See the [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) page for help, it contains links to documents you'll need to read.

Comment: Already looked at that documentation - could not find a way to generate access token for my own GMail account.

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it many months ago.  What exactly did you try?  There's a web page to manage all your OAuth credentials at Google, did you find it?

Comment: @BillShannon: To clarify, did you try logging in using your own GMail account, or allowing users to login using "their" accounts to send the mail? I can easily find the documentation for the latter. If you can, please share the link for the web page you mention?

Comment: The JavaMail Android page links to the [JavaMail OAuth2 page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2), which links to the [Google OAuth2 instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) and the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).  On that page select Credentials and you can manage your OAuth2 credentials that allow access to your account.  Since you read all those pages and tried this already, tell us more exactly what you did and what happened.

Comment: @BillShannon: Thanks for being patient with my questions. I have updated my question with what I tried so far. The documentation about this is so difficult to find :S

Comment: Don't use `new SMTPTransport`, use `session.getTransport("smtp")`.  Get rid of the socketFactory setting.  The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  The access token is supplied instead of the password, as described on the [JavaMail OAuth2 page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2); there's no need to encode it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you have any recommendations for a library to fetch and refresh access token? Based on an hour of searching, I can't find anything that authorizes using client id and secret. I looked into [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) and [Google-OAuth-Java-Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client). I can, of course, manually send HTTP requests for doing this, but I am looking for as easier way.

Comment: No good recommendation, sorry, but if you find one you like, let us know!